# How CloudWatch deals with counter resets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an alerts system which is currently powered by Prometheus and I need to port it to CloudWatch.

Prometheus is aware of [counter resets](https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work) so I can, let's say, calculate the [`rate()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) in the last 24h seamlessly, without handling the counter resets myself.

Is CloudWatch aware of this too?

Answer (score 1):

Rate function is available in [CloudWatch Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html), defined as:

> Returns the rate of change of the metric per second. This is
>   calculated as the difference between the latest data point value and
>   the previous data point value, divided by the time difference in
>   seconds between the two values.

So you would need to modify the way you emit the metric to not reset the counter. A possible workaround could be to increase the number of datapoints to alarm, for example you can configure your alarms so they transition to alarm if 2 or more datapoints are less or equal to (<=) 0, this way you'll avoid to get an alarm when the reset occurs.